# How do I grant someone else access to my linux server

Tags: ssh, permissions, sudo

If you administer a Linux server, what steps do you take to properly grant someone else access?

Assuming they will log in over `ssh`, don't already have an account, and will need root access. (Temporarily).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Creating Account

When granting someone access to a Linux system you usually use the command `useradd`.

```
$ useradd someuser
```

#### Granting Filesystem Permissions

If the user will be working with any files on the system, then add them to the corresponding groups based on which files they'll be working with. You can use 
the `usermod` command for this.

```
$ usermod -a -G group1 someuser
```

This will append the user to the group `group1`.

#### Granting Sudo Permissions

Once their account's been created I'll grant them very specific `sudo` rights (only if needed) using the `visudo` command.

See the `/etc/sudoers` file for more info on how to grant specific rights. Do not do this:

```
someuser    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

unless you intend to give them full root access to the system. Also think about setting a time frame for how long the account should be valid. You might want to set a timeout on it so that it's only valid for a window of time.

If they need to just run the `date` command for example:

```
Cmnd_Alias DATE=/bin/date
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: DATE
```

Also you might want to create Unix groups based on roles, perhaps `myadmins` & `regusers`. Then use these groups in your `sudoers` file when granting access.

```
%myadmins   ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%regusers   ALL=(ALL)       DATE
```