# Error in removing a directory: Directory not empty

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, delete

I try to remove a directory (rm -rf) and I get:

```
rm: cannot remove 'EMBA': Directory not empty
```

moreover when I try to list the directory I get:

```
ls: reading directory 'EMBA': Input/output error
```

the directory EMBA has 777 as permission and no program is using it.

The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04 and the file system is NTFS.

***UPDATE***

Following the roaima answer I try to:

1 - Check the recent output from dmesg or journalctl -k to look for messages corresponding to disk I/O errors

```
I can't find any error messages
```

2 - Check the SMART attributes to see if the disk is dying, or whether it's just the filesystem (smartctl -x)

```
I think there is notting relevant

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   080   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       108362796
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       39
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   076   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       37146160
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3456 (84 124 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       38
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   061   040    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 24/34)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       15
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       643
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 19 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   080   064   000    Old_age   Always       -       108362796
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       667h+38m+56.521s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       6276317084
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8419504151
```

3 - Check the filesystem with ntfsfix. I get:

```
 Mounting volume... OK
 Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
 Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
 NTFS volume version is 3.1.
 NTFS partition /dev/sdb2 was processed successfully.
```

4 - Check the filesystem using a Windows OS

```
Windows has encountered errors on the volume
```

**After fix the error and reboot the system the error in removing the directory was solved**

Comment: Are you just using `ls` to list the contents, or are you using `ls -al`? Also, check this out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory

Comment: I try both. Same result. I get and Input/output error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filesystem or disk has failed (`Input/output error`). Things you should try include,

1. Check the recent output from `dmesg` or `journalctl -k` to look for messages corresponding to disk I/O errors
2. Check the SMART attributes to see if the disk is dying, or whether it's just the filesystem (`smartctl -x /dev/sdb`, replacing `sdb` with the correct device name for the disk)
3. Check the filesystem (`ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`, replacing `sdb1` with the correct device name *and* partition number)
4. Check the filesystem using a Windows OS