# Occasional I/O Errors when attempting to transfer some files but others work fine

Tags: rhel, io, file-transfer

I'm running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux and when I attempt to transfer files through the file browser from one machine to a new directory on a server, I run into an issue where some files are able to be transferred but other files will result with an popup stating an error:

> There was an error copying the file into "(the directory)".
> Error opening file "(the file attempting to be transfered)": Input/Output Error

I was able to add the directory to the `fstab` and successfully mount the directory on the server; I am also able to access the directory and look at the files without any issues. I'm mounting to an ip address and then folders within the address and using nfs to transfer.

When I execute `ls -l` and look at the permissions for the directory, it shows that I have

> drwxrwxrwx

When I connect directly to the server, the machine has an option for an online file explorer. I am able to use the explorer to successfully upload said files that failed to transfer when I try it the normal drag and drop way. The explorer moves files at a much slower rate and is limited to 1 file at a time. This will be an issue for when I have to move many files over the network.

When I look at issues concerning I/O Errors, the common suggestion seems to be a hardware [issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1361997/error-reading-from-file-input-output-error) , things like hardware failing, corruption, or bad sectors, but because I am able to access the directory this can't be the case?

Does a file have to be openable in order to transfer it? I am able to open the file on the system without an issue though. When I use the web explorer to upload the same file, it is openable as well.

`dmesg` has many lines of code following but I don't see any evidence of the disk [failing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory).

EDIT: The output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` is

> ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f0120 00024 (v02 kontrn)
> ACPI: XSDT 00000000acffe1c0 000F4 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC
> 00000002)
> ACPI: FACP 00000000acffb000 0010C (v05 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: DSDT 00000000acfdc000 1AC20 (v02 kontrn          00000000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: FACS 00000000acf9b000 00040
> ACPI: ASF! 00000000acffd000 000A5 (v32 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: HPET 00000000acffa000 00038 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: APIC 00000000acff9000 00098 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: MCFG 00000000acff8000 0003C (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: WDAT 00000000acff7000 00104 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfdb000 00250 (v02 kontrn          00000000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfd7000 0342F (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfd5000 012B4 (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfd3000 018F3 (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfd0000 024AB (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfcc000 03B68 (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfc9000 02CDB (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfc8000 0032C (v02 kontrn          00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfc7000 00539 (v02 kontrn          00003000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfc6000 00B74 (v02 kontrn          00003000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfc0000 05D9C (v02 kontrn          00003000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: SLIC 00000000acfbf000 00176 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: UEFI 00000000acfbe000 00042 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: TCPA 00000000acfbd000 00032 (v02    PTL  CRESTLN 06040000      00005A52)
> ACPI: SSDT 00000000acfbc000 00671 (v01 Intel_ TpmTable 00001000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: POAT 00000000acee7000 00055 (v03 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: BATB 00000000acfbb000 00046 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: FPDT 00000000acfba000 00044 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: UEFI 00000000acfb9000 002CE (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> ACPI: DMAR 00000000acfb7000 000B8 (v01 kontrn kontrnhw 00000002 PTEC 00000002)
> Zone ranges:
> DMA      [mem 0x00001000-0x00ffffff]
> DMA32    [mem 0x01000000-0xffffffff]
> Normal   [mem 0x100000000-0x44f5fffff]
> Movable zone start for each node
> Early memory node ranges
> node   0: [mem 0x00001000-0x0009cfff]
> node   0: [mem 0x00100000-0x0fffffff]
> node   0: [mem 0x1000b000-0x9a351fff]
> node   0: [mem 0x100000000-0x44f5fffff]
> Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 4038248
> Policy zone: Normal
> ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
> ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: View and update with x86_energy_perf_policy(8)
> ACPI: All ACPI Tables successfully acquired
> MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
> #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7 OK
> ACPI: Executed 22 blocks of module-level executable AML code
> ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
> ACPI: SSDT ffff8a33ff0fa000 003D3 (v02  PmRef  Cpu0Cst 00003001 INTL  20120711)
> ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
> ACPI: SSDT ffff8a33ff17a000 005AA (v02  PmRef    ApIst 00003000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
> ACPI: SSDT ffff8a31261a3600 00119 (v02  PmRef    ApCst 00003000 INTL 20120711)
> ACPI: GPE 0x1F active on init
> ACPI: Enabled 9 GPEs in block 00 to 3F
> pci 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
> pci 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI - using ISA IRQ 11
> Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
> xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
> xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI - using ISA IRQ 11
> usb: port power management may be unreliable
> i8042: No controller found
> tmpfs: Bad mount option huge
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
> nct7802: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
> i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: BIOS is accessing SMBus registers
> i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: Driver SMBus register access inhibited
> ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 37
> Failed to set pin attr for GSI37
> iTCO_wdt: I/O address 0x1860 already in use, device disabled
> iTCO_wdt: probe of iTCO_wdt.0.auto failed with error -16
> hid-generic 0003:413C:2101.0001: usb_submit_urb(ctrl) failed: -19

EDIT: I'm not sure if this information makes a difference but when I execute `ls -l /(the server directory that I mounted)` the output is

> total 190
> drwxrwxrwx  3   100 bin 3   Dec 11  2019    Folder1
> drwxrwxrwx  3   100 bin 3   Jan 21  2020    Folder2
> drwxrwxrwx  3   100 bin 3   Jan 21  2020    Folder3
> drwxrwxrwx  3   100 bin 3   Jan 21  2020    Folder4
> drwxrwxrwx  3   100 bin 3   Jan 29  2020    Folder5
> drwxrwxrwx  8   root    root    10  Sep 14  2021    Folder6

Comment: Are you asking for all the lines of code that follow after the commands? The output of `dmesg` has about 1100 lines, I executed `dmesg`, `umount` the drive, ran `dmesg`, then `mount` the drive, and ran `dmesg` a final time and no new lines of code ran after the sequence mentioned prior. When I execute `smartctl -a /dev/device` it mentions that  

/dev/device Unable to detect the device type .

  

I'm still capable of accessing the drive and all it's contents, make new folders and copy some folders but I'll still run into the same issue.

Comment: Are there any extra steps/issue I should be aware of if the folder I'm trying to mount is from a Windows OS while the machine I'm using is RHEL? I'm not sure if this could cause an issue or not because there's another same machine that is configured and has no issues transferring files.

Comment: From what I've read `dmesg` outputs messages produced by the drivers and because mounting the drives isn't producing any outputs in `dmesg` the information from `dmesg` isn't relevant? When I plug in a mouse and keyboard I do get new lines from the output.  
I don't believe I have the drive set to auto mount and because the `dmesg` are time stamped, so the messages my speculation is that they are from other issues and not the mounting. I scanned through the lines of code and don't see any mentions towards the devices I'm using.  I can post the output if it's necessary,

Comment: I can post the output for `smartctl` but I thought I already did " /dev/device Unable to detect the device type"

Comment: This system I'm using has always been built on Linux and there's nothing I can do about that so I'm stuck learning Linux...  Regarding `smartctl` I see what you mean now with the specifying the device, is there something specific I should be looking for? I'm still trying to figure out which specific device it is because there are multiple `nvme1`, `nvme2`,and `nvme3` as well as "n1" and "n1p1" with the 3 aforementioned devices.  For all the devices the  "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED"

Comment: I have to copy the logs from the machine before I can post them. I assume you would only want to see the `smartctl` logs when I can find the specific drive they're associated with correct?

Comment: The directory I'm having issues with is on a server PC running Windows, and not on the local machine where I'm experiencing this issue. That being said, I should still be able to find the special or device file for the drive I'm mounting in  [`/dev`](https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/dev.html) correct? As in I should be able to find the directory where I mounted the server somwhere in `dev` like the link shows?

Answer (score 0):

The typical encounter for an I/O Error issue seems to refer to some sort of hardware issue, but I'm not sure if the solution I found falls under that category.

Rather than using "defaults" options for `/etc/fstab` I set the options to `rw,noexec` and have not experienced any issues with running into an I/O error when I attempt to transfer files.

EDIT: It works for some files but occasionally will still get I/O errors when transferring some files